# How to count the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

How i can count the rows between the two dates.

```
SELECT Count(DATEDIFF(day, ReceiptDate,GETDATE()))
 As TotalDays 
 From JobDetails 
  Where Receiptdate Between DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) and DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())
   AND RepairCompleted='N'
  Group By ReceiptDate
```

for example i want to check 30 to 90 days not completed jobs count.

Comment: Google for 'Case' in sql ... you could use that one to finish what you asked for

Comment: When you use `between`, the lower value needs to go first., so the operands are in the wrong order.

Comment: @Veljko89 not correct, the error here is the GROUP BY should be excluded and the BETWEEN should have swapped the 2 parameters. The COUNT should be replace with COUNT(*) but that will not change the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Count(*) As TotalDays 
FROM JobDetails 
WHERE Receiptdate >= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE()) 
AND Receiptdate <= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
AND RepairCompleted='N'
```

Comment: It returns 0 , but there is jobs in between these days

Comment: I am sorry to ask , how you are checking these condition? i mean what is the idea.

Comment: I don't understand your question.